# Netlify link with deployId is different from the app link

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I have an app hosted in Netlify,

I've deployed at link:
https://[deployId]--[App name].netlify.app with no problems.

But, in the main link: https://[App name].netlify.app :
there is differences !!
[image: https://[deployId]--[App name].netlify.app]

[image: https://[App name].netlify.app]

and the "classes" route not found!!

What is the wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has occurred when I **stopped auto publishing** after deploying from Github repository,
then using Netlify CLI to deploy from git directly.

But when I got back to auto publishing from Github repository,
The problem has been resolved.